# Переписать код Python в код JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, алгоритм

Имеется Python код, который нужно переписать под JavaScript

Код:

```js
import itertools

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
y = set()
z = 6

for x in itertools.combinations(x,z):
    y.add(x)
print(y)
```

Данный код передаёт в переменную 'y' все возможные **уникальные** комбинации элементов массива 'x'. Длина получаемых комбинаций равна 'z'

Пример результата:

{(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10), ..., ...}

Нашёл порт библиотеки itertools на JS, однако в нём нет необходимого мне метода itertools.combinations(), однако присутствует intertools.permutations(), который мне не подходит.

[itertools.js](https://github.com/nvie/itertools.js/)

Answer (score 2):

Имея готовый алгоритм для перестановок типа `next_permutation`, сочетания получить нетрудно.

Создайте массив длиной `n`, содержащий `n-k` нулей и `k` единиц.

Запустите на нём генерацию перестановок.

Для каждой перестановки используйте те элементы из вашего начального массива, на чьих индексах в перестановке стоят единицы. В вашем случае элементы массива - просто числа от `1` до `n`, поэтому при обработке перестановки, встретив на `i`-м месте единицу, записывайте в сочетание  число `i+1`.

Таким образом, перестановке `[0,1,1,0]` соответствует комбинация `[2,3]`

**Edit**

Как подсказал Stanislav Volodarskiy, в `itertools.js` генератор перестановок использует перестановку индексов, так что на массиве с неуникальными элементами работать будет неоптимально.

Вот код получения следующей в лексикографическом порядке перестановки, основанный на сравнениях самих элементов, [взятый отсюда](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm) (там есть ещё версия с компаратором). Впрочем, код генерации непосредственно сочетаний уже дали, так что приведённая схема полезна только в контексте общего образования.

```
/* 
 * Next lexicographical permutation algorithm (JavaScript)
 * by Project Nayuki, 2018. Public domain.
 * https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm
 */

"use strict";


/* Basic version */
/* 
 * Computes the next lexicographical permutation of the specified array of numbers in place,
 * returning whether a next permutation existed. (Returns false when the argument
 * is already the last possible permutation.)
 */
function nextPermutation(array) {
    // Find non-increasing suffix
    var i = array.length - 1;
    while (i > 0 && array[i - 1] >= array[i])
        i--;
    if (i <= 0)
        return false;
    
    // Find successor to pivot
    var j = array.length - 1;
    while (array[j] <= array[i - 1])
        j--;
    var temp = array[i - 1];
    array[i - 1] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
    
    // Reverse suffix
    j = array.length - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Вы потратите много лишнего времени перебираю одни и те же комбинации. Перестановок `N!` а вам нужно `Cnk(N, 6)`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Отнюдь, перестановок массива (00...000111111) ровно столько, сколько сочетаний (при использовании любого алгоритма next_permutation)

Comment: В библиотеке [itertools.js](https://github.com/nvie/itertools.js/blob/main/src/itertools.js#L334) генератор перестановок не обращает внимания на содержимое переставляемого массива. Он породит `N!` повторяющихся вариантов.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Ну что ж, такое тоже бывает нужно. ОК, раз вопрос опирается на  itertools.js, удалю ответ.

Comment: Лучше добавьте next_permutations на JS. Ваше решение хорошее.

Answer (score 2):

Генератор комбинаций `combinations` порождает комбинации в лексикографическом порядке. Для каждой комбинации вызывается функция `cb`.

Функция `array_combs` применяет генератор к массиву как в вашем вопросе.

```js
const combinations = (n, k, cb) => {
    console.assert(Number.isInteger(n));
    console.assert(Number.isInteger(k));
    console.assert(0 <= k);
    console.assert(0 <= n);
    if (k > n) {
        return;
    }

    const a = [...Array(k).keys()];

    cb(a);
    outer:
    while (true) {
        for (let i = k - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            const b = a[i] + 1 - i;
            if (b <= n - k) {
                for (let j = i; j < k; ++j) {
                    a[j] = b + j;
                }
                cb(a);
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
};

const array_combs = (a, k) => {
    const combs = [];
    combinations(a.length, k, s => {
        combs.push(s.map(i => a[i]));
    });
    return combs;
};

console.log(array_combs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3))
```

> ```
> [
>   [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 4 ],
>   [ 1, 2, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 6 ],
>   [ 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 3, 5 ],
>   [ 1, 3, 6 ], [ 1, 4, 5 ],
>   [ 1, 4, 6 ], [ 1, 5, 6 ],
>   [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 5 ],
>   [ 2, 3, 6 ], [ 2, 4, 5 ],
>   [ 2, 4, 6 ], [ 2, 5, 6 ],
>   [ 3, 4, 5 ], [ 3, 4, 6 ],
>   [ 3, 5, 6 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ]
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Это исходная функция на Python:**

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

**А это моя попытка перевести в JavaScript:**

```js
function combinations(iterable, r){
    let arr = [...iterable];
    let len = arr.length;
    if(r > len) return;

    let combs = [];
    findCombs(arr,r);
    function findCombs(arr,n,last=0,comb=[]){
        for(let i=last; i<len; i++){
            let cur = [...comb,arr[i]];
            if(cur.length == n){
                combs.push(cur);
                continue;
            }
            findCombs(arr,n,i+1,cur);
        }
    }
    return combs;
}


console.log(combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],6));
```

Вычисление комбинаций дело трудоемкое, размер изначального массива я сократил.